# Maven Resources plugin ignoring exclusion list

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

## TL; DR

Maven's *Resources* plugin doesn't seem to respect `excludes` elements in the resource configuration.

## Setting

I have a large Java/Dart project where I need to deploy a WAR file that has both my UI and my backend in separate JARs. I want to cut down on the size of the deployed file, and I want to drop certain folders from the WAR. Based on the [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html), I thought I could simply set `exclude`s in my plugin configuration, and it won't copy over the unnecessary folders. However, it seems the *Resources* plugin is outright ignoring these, despite, the Maven model package including a `setExcludes` function.

## Current Attempts

So far, I've tried two main approaches. My configuration is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>web.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>appengine-web.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/web/_el/*</exclude>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/pages/frontend/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/_el/js/frontend/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/_el/dart/app/dashboard/lib/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/_el/dart/app/dashboard/.dart_tool/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```

I tried to use this config inside the `execution` element, as well as outside from directly under the `plugin` element, but both times it was ignored, and *everything* in the `webapp` directory was copied over mindlessly.
On a hunch, I did try setting `filtering` to true, but that just ate up all the memory in my computer, and it didn't even work - what it did process was copied over.

I also tried using the *Shade* plugin, but gave up on that pretty quickly, as the `DontIncludeResourceTransformer` only permits suffix-filtering, which is not adequate for my use case.

## Question

So what am I doing wrong? Based on the docs, I believe the plugin should respect my `excludes` list and skip the vast majority of files, but it's evidently not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apache `**maven war plugin**`.
The WAR Plugin is responsible for collecting all artifact dependencies, classes and resources of the web application and packaging them into a web application archive.

It is possible to include or exclude certain files from the WAR file, by using the  and  configuration parameters. They each take a comma-separated list of Ant file set patterns. You can use wildcards such as ** to indicate multiple directories and * to indicate an optional part of a file or directory name.

Here is an example where we exclude all JAR files from WEB-INF/lib:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

Comment: Well I'll be ... surprised. I wonder why the _Resources_ plugin copies them over in the first place to be picked up into the WAR...